# Рассыпаться — это сколько минимум?

Tags: семантика

[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F):

> Рассыпаться — оказаться разбросанным, лежащим в виде мелких частей на поверхности.

Сколько минимум "мелких частей"?

Например, "рассыпаться на три части" — это семантически корректный вариант?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По моим ощущениям — нет, некорректно.

1. Рассыпался — это когда нельзя в один беглый взгляд посчитать количество получившихся кусочков. Иначе корректно будет сказать 'распался';
2. рассыпался — это когда размер получившихся кусочков разительно меньше изначального объекта. Иначе корректно будет сказать 'развалился'.

Повторю и подчеркну: это лишь по моим ощущениям.